# Simple way to diff a file in local SFDX project against Production version with SFDX

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, diff

Although we use git repos to track all our projects, I oftentimes want to do another check against a production file before I overwrite it with an `sfdx force:source:deploy` command (because as much as a git repo is kept up-to-date, you never know what renegade changes have been made to Production...)

Is there a simple `sfdx` workflow or command to bring in that file and compare against my local project version?  Context: I use VS Code and git for day-to-day development.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

VS Code has an option to detect conflicts on deployment for non-source-tracked orgs. Go to Settings > Salesforce Feature Previews > Salesforcedx-vscode-core: Detect Conflicts At Sync. Note that this is still a limited feature, so some caution is advised.

In the interim, if I want to check for differences, I usually do:

```
git checkout -b temp-branch
git add force-app
git commit -m "temp commit for compare"
sfdx force:source:retrieve -p force-app
git diff
```

This gives me a line-by-line analysis of everything. I can also use `--name-only` just to get a feel for which files are affected.

Comment: Just a simple `git checkout -b prod-20200729` and `sfdx force:source:retrieve -p force-app -u MyProductionOrg` did the trick very nicely.  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried using the Salesforce official Diff Feature on the Extension Pack for Salesforce

https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/source-diff/

From the terminal, run sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-diff.

After the installation is complete, @salesforce/sfdx-diff appears in the list of installed plugins when running sfdx plugins.

Use the vscode menu to take the diff

[image]

This requires enabling the preview flag from your vscode settings

[image]

Comment: Wow, not sure why this plugin is not part of the normal sfdx package, nice find! This is really nifty, but oftentimes my default org is set to a sandbox, but want to do the diff against the Production org.  Changing the default org is quick enough in VS code though, will give it a try

Comment: Worth noting - the underlining sfdx command only works when right-clicking the file and using the menu dropdown as in your screenshot.  If you try to do the command line: `sfdx force:source:diff -p force-app/main/default/classes/MyController.cls -u MyProductionOrg`, you get the following error message (as of Summer '20): "This command is currently in a beta program for usage with the Salesforce Extensions for VSCode."

Comment: @BrianMiller you can use the `--json` flag in your command to output the file locations that you can then diff. See my separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

After installing the `sfdx:source:diff` tool from @Mohith Shrivastava's response, you can use the `--json` flag to return the locations of the remote and local files that VS Code uses to diff. You can then pass those files to `git diff` to see the diff in the command line.

Here is the whole command:

```sh
SFDX_DIFF_JSON=$(sfdx force:source:diff -p force-app/main/default/classes/MyController.cls -u MyProductionOrg --json)
git diff $(echo ${SFDX_DIFF_JSON} | jq '.result.remote' -r) $(echo ${SFDX_DIFF_JSON} | jq '.result.local' -r)
```